# Float, object, string, datatype conversion

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe with these two columns. I want to sum those two columns and do: `sumgroup1 = np.sum(dfgroup1[['StartEarliestDifference','LatestEndDifference']].values)`

This results in the following error: `unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'`

```
StartEarliestDifference LatestEndDifference
    27.0                           218
    5.0                             8
    2.0                             3
```

StartEarliestDifference = float64 , and LatestEndDifference = object

I tried to convert the object in a float, with the following line :

```
dfgroup1['LatestEndDifference'].convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
```

Unfortunately the LatestEndDifference is not changed to a float and the sum results in the same error. What's wrong with my method?

Comment: Most pandas operations are not inplace and return a copy, if in doubt always consult the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The change of `convert_objects` is not in-place, you have to reassign it:

```
dfgroup1['LatestEndDifference'] = dfgroup1['LatestEndDifference'].convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
```